# Exporting in CMYK in Affinity Designer?

Tags: color, export, cmyk, rgb, affinity-designer

I use Affinity Designer, and I found that although I create the design in CMYK colour model, when I export it as a .jpg or a .png file, the design reverts back to RGB colour model?

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this article relating to the subject https://affinityspotlight.com/article/designing-for-professional-printing/

Comment: There is no such thing as CMYK PNG

Answer (score 2):

This is likely how the developers intended Affinity Designer to work. JPEG and PNG are intended for web-based images where CMYK is not likely to be useful.

You can export as TIFF in CMYK though.

Finally, you can always contact the developers of Affinity Designer and ask if they'll build in support for exporting CMYK PNGs and JPEGs.

Comment: "support for exporting CMYK PNGs" That would be complicated... as PNG is not for CMYK files at all.

Comment: CMYK JPGs is actually very useful if done correctly.